# Overlay AutoCAD drawing on QGIS desktop shapefiles

Tags: qgis, dwg

I have sewerage network data in shapefiles. I want to overlay with drawing.dwg file so i can update shape files in QGIS. How to directly open drawing.dwg file in QGIS desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Project > Import/Export > Import Layers from DWG/DXF`

This will ask you to specify the location of a new geopackage that the imported layers will be added to, and will ask for the source drawing. It can take some time to properly import all the layers but once it has finished they will keep their original CAD symbology.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS doesn't work with .dwg but can open .dxf so your options are :

- If you have autocad (or equivalent) save your .dwg in  dxf format
- Ask your dwg provider to convert it to dxf for you
- Use an online converter to convert your dwg to dxf (an internet search will provide several
  options, as I never used one I can't suggest any)